# Text background color for newlines in TextKit 2

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, textkit

When using `NSTextLayoutManager.addRenderingAttribute(.backgroundColor, value: NSColor.red, for: range)`, the background color for a line is only drawn as far as the last visible character. There is also a thin space between the lines where the background color is not visible.

[image]

Whe using `NSLayoutManager.addTemporaryAttribute(.backgroundColor, value: NSColor.red, forCharacterRange: range)`, the background color is drawn also for newline characters and soft line wraps.

[image]

I would like to achieve the effect of using `NSLayoutManager.addTemporaryAttribute(.backgroundColor, value: NSColor.red, forCharacterRange: range)`, but since I'm targeting TextKit 2, I have to avoid using `NSLayoutManager`. Is there a way to achieve this with `NSTextLayoutManager` or one of the other related classes in TextKit 2?